# Infinite build time for new Project in android Studio Update 2.3

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I have Updated My Android Studio(2.3.0) and the Gradle plugins(Gradle Version: 3.3+) to the Latest one.Existing projects works fine.

But can't able to Create New Project and it takes `infinite time for building the Project` .
Tried all the following Solutions that were mentioned in Stackoverflow

- Gradle plugin Update.
- Invalidate Cache and Restart.
- Delete Cache files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried creating a new Project when android studio off line ?

Comment: Yes. Now I can able to create new Project In Offline Mode.but it fails to Build Again. And Solved it by Setting the Gradle Home Path to Latest Version Ex: C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/gradle/gradle-3.4.1 and added project level Build Dependency classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.0'

Comment: When I first Install Android studio and update it, I let it build until it was finished online. It really took hours. But it was only for the first time

Comment: was build success?

Comment: oh That's great. Happy to hear that